# If $3 - 5i$ is a square root of $z$, find the other root.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, radicals

> If $3 - 5i$ is a square root of $z$, find the other root.

Well, I was under the impression that only the sign in front of the imaginary part would change so the other root would be $3 + 5i$.

However, when I solve for the complex root using de Moivre's theorem, then I get $-3 + 5i$.

Both the real and imaginary parts have changed signs - this seems to go against what I thought was the complex conjugate root theorem?

Comment: would you like to show your working so someone can see what went wrong?

Comment: Consider:  is $z$ real or complex?

Comment: Z is complex - although it does not say, this is the assumption as the unit is on Demoivres. Aah so does that make a difference? If this is the case, is it not possible to use Demoivre's to solve for all roots if z is real?

Comment: If $w$ is a square root, so is $-w$.  So you have to negate $3$ and $5$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have the general property that: $t^2 =(-t)^2$. This holds in $\Bbb C$ as much as it does in $\Bbb  R$. Hence if $z=(3-5i)^2$ then $z=(-(3-5i))^2=(-3+5i)^2$ holds also. On the other hand, we have:

$$(\bar{z})^2=\overline {z^2},$$

which is obvious if you square out $a+bi$ and $a-bi$ or represent them and their squares on an Argand Diagram.

The complex conjugate root theorem is based on

$$(x-z)(x-\bar z)=x^2-(z+\bar z)x+ z\bar z ,$$

for which all coefficients are real, thusly we can see complex solutions to real polynomials. However, the polynomial we might generate from this problem;

$$z^2+16+30i=0$$ does not have real coefficients, so that method can't be used.

Answer (score 5):

If we apply DeMoivre's Theorem, the second root will be a $180$ degree rotation around the pole. So the other root is in fact, $-3 + 5i$ (you're right!). You are confusing the usage of the complex conjugate root theorem, which only applies to polynomials with *real* coefficients, not square roots of complex numbers in the complex plane.

Comment: I see, so it is not possible to use DeMoivre's theorem for polynomials with real coefficients? What if I was asked to find all the cube roots of 8 - how would I know if I am able to use this theorem?

Comment: @McMath It's possible in some scenarios to use DeMoivre's Theorem for certain polynomials (like when solving for $x^n = a$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$), but more generally speaking, it finds and guarantees $k$ solutions to the *complex* equation $z^k = b$ for any $b \in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @McMath you are most certainly right to use DeMoivre's Theorem to find the cube of $8$, but I'm just saying that you are confusing the use of DeMoivre's Theorem with the complex conjugate root theorem.

Comment: Ok, so for finding all the cube roots of 8, I would be able to use DeMoivres and it would generate the same roots regardless of if I'm in the complex plane or real plane? Also, if I'm given a complex root like the root given in my original post, then I'm assuming the teacher would need to specify that z is complex, otherwise I could use the complex conjugate theorem to generate different roots. Thanks

Comment: @McMath You are confusing what the complex conjugate root theorem and DeMoivre's theorem guarantee about certain equations. I recommend watching Khan Academy videos about the two theorems. You seem to have conflated the ideas of what the two different theorems say.

Comment: Well instead of the videos can you please provide a brief clarification? Thanks

Comment: @McMath Unfortunately I can't because the theorems are rooted in two fundamentally different concepts. It will take a solid explanation, longer than a comments section, to explain them to you. You'll have more success looking for lectures about this online.

Comment: Cube roots of $8$: You want to find all solutions of $X^3=8$, in other words the solutions of $X^3-8=0$. Just factor, to get $(X-2)(X^2+2X+4)$. Use quadratic formula to find the roots of the quadratic factor. Please do this computation, and see that your three answers are the same as what you get using DeMoivre.

Answer (score 0):

Polar coordinates:

$z_1= re^{i\alpha}$, given.

$z_1^2= r^2e^{i(2\alpha)}=: z$.

The  roots of $z$ are:

$z_1= re^{i(2\alpha)/2}$,and

$z_2= re^{i[(2\alpha)/2+ (2π)/2]}$;

$z_2= z_1\cdot(e^{iπ})= -z_1$.

Hence $z_2=-3+i5$.